# Where should constants for events go in a C# project

Tags: c#, oop, events, constants, coding-style

I'm extremely new to C# and I had a question of convention:

Where should constants that are associated with an event be stored?

Should they be included in the same place that I define my EventArgs?

As an explain, I want to define different constants for a private field called "_difficulty", and is set through my overridden EventArgs class's constructor.

Let's say the constants were,
public const int EASY = 0, MEDIUM = 1, HARD = 2; (I'm assuming the naming convention is all caps)

Alternatively, I could make a class like "DifficultyConstants", then insert them there.

I was just curious as to what the convention was and would make the most sense for following OOP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are really adding levels like EASY, MEDIUM, HARD, which are at ordinal level from eachother, I would expect an `enum` to be used. Just as in other languages, you could use an `public enum Difficulty {EASY, MEDIUM, HARD}`.

But where do you leave such an enum? If you want it to be used in a lot of different eventArgs, I would recommend using some abstract base class:

```
public class LevelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public enum Difficulty
    { 
        EASY, 
        MEDIUM, 
        HARD 
    }
}
```

**And then, let all your EventArgs inherit from this class.**

Answer (score 12):

The convention is to not do this.  What you're describing would be conventionally implemented as an [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) rather than a set of named integer constants.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an enumeration instead:

```
public enum DifficultyLevel {
  Easy = 0,
  Medium = 1,
  Hard = 2
}
```

That way all the values are defined in a structure that is well defined as being connected to the type, not as loose constants that could be connected to anything.

Declare your private field as:

```
private DifficultyLevel _difficulty;
```

Assign a value like this:

```
_difficulty = DifficultyLevel.Easy;
```

By specifying the numeric values for the enumeration, you can also convert them to and from known integer values if you need to:

```
_difficulty = (DifficultyLevel)1;

int level = (int)_difficulty;
```

Answer (score 2):

Constants should be declared near or in the object they are most commonly associated with in their use. If your primary use of the constants is in creating your custom EventArgs, that sounds like a great place to define them. If they're used everywhere, a Common or CommonUtil library is usually recommended.

One tip; consider creating an enum for these values instead of them being individual constants. They are a related, mutually-exclusive set of values that indicate status; the textbook definition of enum values.

Answer (score 2):

Looks more like you want an enumeration

```
    public enum Difficulty
{
   Easy,
   Medium,
   Hard
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how your code is set up.  In some cases it could be in a common namespace within your project or solution.

I have several projects where it's in a common namespace, i.e. Company.Common